# Child Div Elements Outside of Parent Div

Tags: html, css

I'm running into an issue where my child divs are going outside of their parent div.
I've set my parent div height to be 70px and all child elements height to be 100%.
My child elements (name & search bar) borders are below the parent element border.

My first thought was that there maybe a margin collapse situation, so I added borders to all my divs.

I then thought that maybe my child elements' heights (with their contents) are above my parent's fixed height of 70px. However, after inspecting the Box Model on Chrome Developer Tools, all child heights and widths calculations match the 70px of the parent div. I then tried box-sizing: border-box.

Is there any possible way to fix this error without using the properties: float, flex, grid?

Here is my code snippet:

Code:

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 0 15% 0 15%;
}

ul {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  border: 3px solid teal;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

form {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid teal;
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.div_navBarContainer {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.div_logoContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid lime;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}

.h3_logoName {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 3px teal;
  color: white;
}

.div_linksContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  color: white;
}

.div_searchBarContainer {
  border: 3px solid lime;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
}

.div_signInContainer {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_navBarContainer">
  <div class="div_logoContainer">
    <h3 class="h3_logoName">Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="div_linksContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div_searchBarContainer">
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="div_signInContainer">
    <li>
      <a href="">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">SignUp</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally I would probably use flexbox in a situation like this, but barring that it seems like a vertical alignment issue. For me, putting `vertical-align: top` lined things up, ensuring the top of the child starts at the top of the parent.

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: #212121;
  padding: 0 15% 0 15%;
}

ul {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  border: 3px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}

li {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid orange;
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

a {
  border: 3px solid teal;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
}

form {
  border: 3px solid orange;
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 3px solid teal;
  width: 80%;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.div_navBarContainer {
  margin-top: 200px;
  height: 70px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  border: 3px solid white;
}

.div_logoContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid lime;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.h3_logoName {
  display: inline-block;
  border: solid 3px teal;
  color: white;
}

.div_linksContainer {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  height: 100%;
  width: 30%;
  color: white;
}

.div_searchBarContainer {
  border: 3px solid lime;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40%;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.div_signInContainer {
  border: 3px solid yellow;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 15%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="div_navBarContainer">
  <div class="div_logoContainer">
    <h3 class="h3_logoName">Name</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="div_linksContainer">
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link3</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="">Link4</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="div_searchBarContainer">
    <form action="">
      <input type="text" placeholder="Search" />
    </form>
  </div>
  <div class="div_signInContainer">
    <li>
      <a href="">Login</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">SignUp</a>
    </li>
  </div>
</div>
```